# Why non-invite SIP timer F is not mandatory?

Tags: transactions, sip

In RFC 3261, [Sec. 17.1.2.2 Para 2nd](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3261.txt), "When entering this state, the client
transaction **' should '** set timer F to fire in 64*T1 seconds."

Why Timer F is SHOULD here? Shouldn't it be MUST?

What if i start a non-invite client transaction without Timer F and did not get any response. Then how my transaction is cleared? It will be keep running in my client.

Answer (score 0):

The SHOULD certainly applies to the duration (64*T1), not the fact that timer F is started or not!

Non standard duration values may be more appropriate for some specific network or scenario.

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense now.